# Spring boot JUnit tests pass individually but not when run together

Tags: spring-boot, unit-testing, junit, spring-test

I'm trying to create tests for a `courseRepository` and a `queueRepository`, and all the tests pass when run individually, but not when the whole file is ran.

This is the `courseRepo`:

```
@DataJpaTest
class CourseRepositoryTest {
    @Autowired
    private CourseRepository courseRepository;

    @Autowired
    private TestEntityManager entityManager;

    @BeforeEach
    void setUp() {
        Course course =
                Course.builder()
                .id(1L)
                .name("Fullstack applikasjonsutvikling")
                .code("IDATT2105")
                .semester("V22")
                .queueActive(false)
                .totalWork(6)
                .rules("6_1_6")
                .nrOfStudents(100)
                .build();
        entityManager.persist(entityManager.merge(course));
    }

    @Test
    void findByCodeAndSemester() {
        Course course = courseRepository.findByCodeAndSemester("IDATT2105", "V22").get();
        assertEquals("Fullstack applikasjonsutvikling", course.getName());

    }

    @Test
    void findById() {
        Course course = courseRepository.findById(1L).get();
        assertEquals("Fullstack applikasjonsutvikling", course.getName());
    }

    @Test
    void deleteById(){
        courseRepository.deleteById(1L);
        assertTrue(courseRepository.findById(1L).isEmpty());
    }


}
```

This is the `QueueRepo`:

```
@DataJpaTest
class QueueRepositoryTest {
    @Autowired
    private QueueRepository queueRepository;

    @Autowired
    private TestEntityManager entityManager;

    @BeforeEach
    void setUp() {
        System.out.println("before each called");
        Course course =
                Course.builder()
                        .id(1L)
                        .name("Fullstack applikasjonsutvikling")
                        .code("IDATT2105")
                        .semester("V22")
                        .queueActive(false)
                        .totalWork(6)
                        .rules("6_1_6")
                        .nrOfStudents(100)
                        .build();

        Queue queue = Queue.builder()
                .id(1L)
                .course(course)
                .build();

        entityManager.persist(entityManager.merge(queue));
    }
    @AfterEach
    void teardown(){
        queueRepository.deleteAll();
    }

    @Test
    void getByCourseId() {
        Queue queue = queueRepository.getByCourseId(1L).get();
        assertEquals(1L, queue.getId());
    }

    @Test
    void getByCourseId_falseId(){
        assertTrue(queueRepository.getByCourseId(2L).isEmpty());
    }
}
```

I've tried importing different test annotations to no success and I don't think its scope related, but I may be wrong.

Answer (score 0):

There is no `@AfterEach` on `CourseRepositoryTest`.
They also could be @Before and @After, as you can reuse the same course.

When running against a real DB, you would get duplicate key conflicts.